# How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?

Tags: jquery, stringification

How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?

Answer (score 653, accepted):

I assume you're asking for the full HTML string. If that's the case, something like this will do the trick:

```
$('<div>').append($('#item-of-interest').clone()).html();
```

This is explained in more depth [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-get-full-html-string-including.html), but essentially you make a new node to wrap the item of interest, do the manipulations, remove it, and grab the HTML.

If you're just after a string representation, then go with `new String(obj)`.

## Update

I wrote the original answer in 2009. As of 2014, most major browsers now support `outerHTML` as a native property (see, for example, [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) and [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534310(v=vs.85).aspx))), so you can do:

```
$('#item-of-interest').prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: It sucks that there isn't a method to just do this, but this is a great solution regardless.

Comment: this removes the head and body tags

Comment: Note that ``outerHTML`` only works if there is a single outer element.  ``$("<p></p><p></p>").prop('outerHTML')`` will yield "<p></p>", which may not be what you want.  You'll have to wrap it in a ``<div/>`` or something.

Comment: @user85461 That isn't a valid DOM node, though, so it would be wrong to try to call outerHTML on it to begin with. (Only a tiny subset of what can go in `$(...)` is a valid DOM node.)

Comment: @JohnFeminella exactly. Don't confuse a jQuery object (as per the question) with a DOM node. :)

Comment: @user85461 My point is that, presumably, since you know what you're passing into it, you also know whether it is a valid DOM node or not. Therefore, you should not call `prop('outerHTML')` unless you're sure it is a DOM node. (The OP never clarified what he meant by "a string", since any string representation you can imagine is possible, so it seems like most people assumed they were referring to a DOM node that could be directly represented in HTML.)

Comment: What is wrong with `$('#item-of-interest').html()`?

Comment: @Moss it gives you inner html, or simplier, what is **inside** of element, while outerHtml gives you element **as a whole**

Comment: The 2014 version worked perfectly.  I found another answer that suggested just using element.outerHTML, but that didn't work.  element.prop('outerHTML') did the trick, though.

Comment: Note, that you will lose `data`

Comment: After using the $(element).html() solution for a year, I discovered it does not work for elements within the `<head>...</head>` block.  But, prop('outerHTML') works on those.

Comment: It would be nice to just remove the reference to html() and keep the update so as not to waste our time with stuff that doesn't work.

Answer (score 208):

With jQuery 1.6, this seems to be a more elegant solution:

```
$('#element-of-interest').prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc On Firefox 15.0.1 (linux) it works like a charm.

Answer (score 57):

Just use .get(0) to grab the native element, and get its outerHTML property:

```
var $elem = $('<a href="#">Some element</a>');
console.log("HTML is: " + $elem.get(0).outerHTML);
```

Comment: So much better as it retains my attributes as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Can you be a little more specific? If you're trying to get the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) inside of a tag you can do something like this:

HTML snippet:

```
<p><b>This is some text</b></p>
```

jQuery:

```
var txt = $('p').html(); // Value of text is <b>This is some text</b>
```

Answer (score 10):

The best way to find out what properties and methods are available to an HTML node (object) is to do something like:

```
console.log($("#my-node"));
```

From jQuery 1.6+ you can just use outerHTML to include the HTML tags in your string output:

```
var node = $("#my-node").outerHTML;
```

Comment: it's `$('#my-node').get(0).outerHTML` as in mppfiles' answer

Comment: `.outerHTML` didn't work for me, but `.prop('outerHTML')` did.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery is up in here, so:

```
jQuery.fn.goodOLauterHTML= function() {
    return $('<a></a>').append( this.clone() ).html();
}
```

Return all that HTML stuff:

```
$('div' /*elys with HTML text stuff that you want */ ).goodOLauterHTML(); // alerts tags and all
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work fine for me:

```
$("#id")[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: I was also using this but this doesn't seem to work for Firefox 6.0.1.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't cover text nodes (undefined is printed out).

This code snippet solves it:

```js
var htmlElements = $('<p><a href="http://google.com">google</a></p>↵↵<p><a href="http://bing.com">bing</a></p>'),
    htmlString = '';
    
htmlElements.each(function () {
    var element = $(this).get(0);

    if (element.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        htmlString += element.outerHTML;
    }
    else if (element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        htmlString += element.nodeValue;
    }
});

alert('String html: ' + htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, the accepted answer did not work for me. Yours did!

Answer (score 1):

No need to clone and add to the DOM to use .html(), you can do:

```
$('#item-of-interest').wrap('<div></div>').html()
```

Comment: But doesn't `wrap()` return the wrapped element, *not* the element with which it was wrapped? So this *should* give the html of the `#item-of-interest` *not* it's parent `div` element (unless jQuery's changed since February of 2012).

Comment: Seeing this 10 years later. I just checked and you're right, the wrap is messing it up. It should have been $('#item-of-interest').wrap('<div></div>').parent().html(). But now there is the better native solution in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use the `jQuery.makeArray(obj)` utility function:

```
var obj = $('<p />',{'class':'className'}).html('peekaboo');
var objArr = $.makeArray(obj);
var plainText = objArr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stringify an HTML element in order to pass it somewhere and parse it back to an element try by creating a unique query for the element:

```
// 'e' is a circular object that can't be stringify
var e = document.getElementById('MyElement')

// now 'e_str' is a unique query for this element that can be stringify 
var e_str = e.tagName
  + ( e.id != "" ? "#" + e.id : "")
  + ( e.className != "" ? "." + e.className.replace(' ','.') : "");

//now you can stringify your element to JSON string
var e_json = JSON.stringify({
  'element': e_str
})
```

than

```
//parse it back to an object
var obj = JSON.parse( e_json )

//finally connect the 'obj.element' varible to it's element
obj.element = document.querySelector( obj.element )

//now the 'obj.element' is the actual element and you can click it for example:
obj.element.click();
```

Answer (score -4):

```
new String(myobj)
```

If you want to serialize the whole object to string, use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).