# jQuery trying to build up and then append HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I've put a much simplified example [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/LHukf/).

Basically, I'm trying to build up my HTML and then append the whole thing once I'm done. The JS looks like this:

```
var label = 'My label',
    var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox">').prop({
                id: 'checkboxId',
                name: 'checkboxId',
                checked: visible
            });
    listItem = ('<li class="customise_option"><label>'+checkbox+' '+label+'</label></li>');

$('#mylist').append(checkbox);
$('#myotherlist').append(listItem);
```

Appending just `checkbox` is fine, but if I try to include `checkbox` within my `listItem` variable then I just get:

```
[object Object] My label
```

So, on it's own jQuery is fine with appending my `checkbox` as a string, but when I try to do anything with that it treats it as an object.

Having looked around there are [some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000438/convert-a-jquery-object-and-contents-to-string), but as I'm creating everything in JavaScript (rather than manipulating something that already exists in the DOM) it seems there must be a way to do what I want. Problem is I can't figure it out.

**EDIT**

I simplified my original example too much, not understanding the problem fully. I have updated [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/LHukf/) to show that on my `checkbox` I need to be able to add a bunch of properties. So, the `checked` property will be reliant on something else. As such, I need `$` so I can access jQuery's `prop` function (I think).

Comment: why do you have $ while defining checkbox as a string ? You are selecting the input.

Comment: @PatsyIssa That's not correct.

Comment: @undefined it's the basics of jquery mate $('selector') ....

Comment: @PatsyIssa If you pass a valid markup as a string to jQuery, it will create the elements, in this case a checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

```
var label = 'My label',
    checkbox = '<input type="checkbox">';
    listItem = '<li class="customise_option"><label>'+checkbox+' '+label+'</label></li>';

$('#mylist').append(checkbox);
$('#myotherlist').append(listItem);
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHukf/1/). If you're adding HTML markup, all you need are strings; you weren't far away.

Comment: You should explain the jQuery object conflict so that he knows what went wrong and how to prevent it in future.

Comment: Well simply put, when you want to insert HTML, you insert strings. And then, once the HTML is on the page, you can use jQuery to access that HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

`checkbox` is a jquery object, when you say `string + checkbox` you're casting `checkbox` to a string (which gives `[object Object]`) and then appending it. you need to use `append()` there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox">')` returns a jquery object.

Either stick to jquery objects and use methods like `text()` etc, or stick to appending string representations of HTML. Just dont mix it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the checkbox is an object.
With this code, works

var label = 'My label',
    checkbox = '',
    listItem = ''+checkbox+' '+label+'';

$('#mylist').append(checkbox);
$('#myotherlist').append(listItem);