# Return the tag AND contents of an element in jquery

Tags: jquery

So I'm iterating through a list of returned elements in a jQuery .each() call and what I want to do is return a string that has the contents AND tag of the element in question.  For example:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="bar">Blah blah</div>
</div>

If I ran a $('.bar').each(function()) I want it to return  
'<div class="bar">Blah blah</div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tag = this.outerHTML || $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
```

This uses the browser's `outerHTML` property if it is available, otherwise it creates a new `<div>`, makes a clone of the element, places it inside, and get's the `.html()` of the `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was cruising through jQuery docs looking for outerHTML, didn't realize it is native JS.

Answer (score 0):

you want the html of the parent node.

```
$('.bar').each( function() { alert( $(this).parent().html(); ) } );
```

although that is going to get you all sibling nodes as well. You could get get the actual DOM node with

```
    $(this).get(0).outerHTML
```

and then

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer here: [How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)

```
function stringElement(jqElement){
     return $('<div>').append(jqElement.clone()).remove().html();
}
```