# Getting HTML from XML with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, cdata

I've got an XML document that contains a tag that has well-formed HTML content. I need to get that HTML into my page using JavaScript. However, due to CMS issues, the HTML CANNOT be escaped with < ![CDATA[ ]]> or anything else, and the <> must be present, not encoded to &lt ; &gt ;

```
<submenu>
    <content>
        <div>
            <h3>Hello World</h3>
            <p>Lorem <a href="ipsum.html">ipsum</a></p>
        </div>
    </content>
</submenu>
```

I've used jQuery to get the XML and put the submenu's into an array. I'm able to get the text with:

```
$(menuArray[n]).find('content').text();
```

However, this just returns "Hello World Lorem ipsum". I need the HTML. Unfortunately jQuerys' .html() method doesn't work with XML.

Is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works for me using browser's xml parser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not overly *clean* but could you not use something like found in this example [JQuery Object to Sring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string) and do something like...
 `var myHTML = $('<div>').append($(menuArray[n]).find('content').clone()).remove().html();`

Ugly I know but *should* work

Comment: This will thrown SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3) on IE9

Comment: I Solved the problem told by me in the last comment. By setting dataType to "html"

Answer (score 0):

@Sam Nicholson gave us a good idea. I used it for a while, but now i solved my problem through another way.

By setting AJAX property **'dataType'** to **'html'** and forcing the server response to be  **text/html** rather than **text/xml**. jQuery will let you use **.html()** to manipulate the nodes of your XML tree sent from your server

Comment: I think some versions of IE cannot read XML as HTML, anyone has some advice on that?