# jQuery with uncomplete DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

My problem is related to jQuery and the DOM elements. I need a template like the following:

```
var threadreply = " <li class='replyItem'>"
                + "     <div class='clearfix'>"
                + "         ${tittle}"
                + "     </div>"
                + " </li>"
                ;
$.template( "threadreply", threadreply );
```

As you can see, this is a list element. My problem is when I parse it with `$.tmpl`, which retrieves a valid DOM element without the `<li> </li>` tags.

```
liElement = liElement + $.tmpl("threadreply", {"tittle": "hello"} ).html();
```

Is there any way I can retrieve the element without reformatting?

I know I can do it with a template with a valid `ul` tag and inside an each jQuery template loop, but I'm not working with JSONs, I can't convert my data structures to JSON.

The full example is as follow:

```
var threadreply = " <li class='replyItem'>"
                + "     <div class='clearfix'>"
                + "         ${tittle}"
                + "     </div>"
                + " </li>"
                ;
$.template( "threadreply", threadreply );

var liElement = "";
for( var i = 0; i < 150; i ++ ){
    liElement = liElement + $.tmpl("threadreply", {"tittle": "hello"} ).html();
}
$(liElement).appendTo("#ULElement");
```

EDITED

I found a workaround with this thread: [JQuery Object to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string) wich consists on wraping each DOM element returned by the `$.tmpl` in a `div` before get the `.html()` of the object:

```
liElement = liElement + $('<div>').append( $.tmpl("threadreply", {"tittle": "hello"} )).html();
```

With 300 elements it takes aprox 290ms in process all elements. With the `appendTo()` inside the loop, it takes more than 800ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not get the 'li' element because when you do

```
liElement = liElement + $.tmpl("threadreply", {"tittle": "hello"} ).html();
```

you get the *contained* html (or innerhtml) of the 'li' element.

html:

```
<ul id="titleList">
</ul>
```

js:

```
$.tmpl("threadreply", {"tittle": "hello"}).appendTo('#titleList');
```

Comment: If i do what you say, when i `alert(liElement);`  is full of `[object]`. I cant do nothing with them.

Comment: you can use jQuery's .appendTo to achieve what you want.
i updated the answer for you.

Comment: I know i can do this, but when i have a loop with 150 iterations, i dont want to `appentTo();` directcly to an DOM object. Instead i want to collect all in a variable and then, when the loop finish, append it. Im going to update the question with full code.

Comment: you could create a new, empty jQuery element and use appendTo on that, then append your new, now filled jQuery element to your document somewhere.

Comment: i made some test, and thought you cant appentTo in to an empty element. Despite that, in that way you are doing 150 appendTo(); witch takes really much time.

Comment: I update the question to include the best workaround i found so far.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the string and not a real DOM element. Just use:

```
liElement = liElement + $.tmpl("threadreply", {"tittle": "hello"});
```

Outside the loop, you need to wrap the HTML you just generated into a new element, and then replace the former `li`:

```
$('<li />').html(liElement).replaceAll('li#existingLiID');
```

Comment: i cant do nothing with the liElement after the loop, if i dont take the `.html()`

Comment: Seems like you need to wrap the HTML you created into a new `li` item, and then replace the former `li`. See my update.

Comment: Thats still not working. The real problem is that the $.tmpl returns a DOM object and i cant concatenate it to a variable. If y use `.html()` to retrieve the html of the object, its return the innerHtml of the first DOM object, in this case the `li` wich is the `div`.