# view xml data in jquery

Tags: jquery

how do i display xml data using jquery? i don't need to parse it i just need to display it to the user on the page.

Here's my current code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Service2.svc/DoWork",
    data: "{}",
    processdata: true,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert($(jqXHR).responseXML);
    }); $("#Text1").val($(response));
}, error: function() {
    alert("error");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(jqXHR.xml);
    }
});
```

Comment: @user , post your jquery ajax code , where do you want to display ??/

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to parse it anyways due to the < and > . Use the 'load' method.

Comment: okay.. how bout if I display the xml in alert method? i've tried  alert($(xml)); but it just displays "object [object]". any ideas?

Comment: Please let us see your code. Why are you using the '$' char before the variable? JavaScript is not Perl or PHP ;) .

Comment: Because the jQuery function `$()` converts a HTML string (hopefully XML) into a jQuery object when passed as a first parameter. Like so: `$('<div class="foo">asd</div>');`

Comment: `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Service2.svc/DoWork",
            data: "{}",
            processdata: true, //True or False
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert($(jqXHR).responseXML);
                });

                $("#Text1").val($(response));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've stored the response XML into the variable `xml`.

I think this should work:

```
alert($('<div>').append($(xml).clone()).remove().html());
```

Credit goes here: [How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **result.responseText**
where result is the object returned in your **complete** function