# I want to save an element's html to a variable

Tags: jquery, html

I know how to use .html() to grab the html inside of my selected element, like so:

```
<div id="outside>
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

using something like

```
var span = $('#outside).html();
```

will grab my span as the html.  My problem is when I have

```
<img id="image" src="image.png">
```

How can I assign the html, as a string, to a variable?  Using

```
var image = $('#image').html()
```

gives me an empty string.

```
var image = $('#image')[0]
```

appears to get the html I want, but its actually still an object.

Comment: What you want from the image.. SRC path?

Comment: I want a string "<img id="image" src="image.png">"

Comment: I'm almost sure that your answer is **[here][1]**.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string

Comment: Thanks Marcelo Assis, that worked!  For those wondering, the string is $('<div>').append($('#image')).clone()).remove().html()

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var myAwesomeHTML = $('#image')[0].outerHTML
```

update:

```
$("<div></div>").append($("#image")).html()
```

Comment: Did you close your img tag with / ?

Comment: Sorry that solution only seems to work in Safari. Try my updated solution.

Comment: I like your enthusiasm with `myAwesomeHTML`

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done by wrapping an element to it and getting theparent element's HTML like this

```
 var a=$('#image');
 a.wrap('<span class="ab"></span>');
 var htmlOfEle=$('.ab').html();
```

Here is the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/CR2PD/2/
It may help you..

**Edit:**

Without using jQuery, you can do like below

```
var el = document.getElementById('image');
html = el.outerHTML
```

Comment: Better to do .outerHTML instead of adding some element around what you want. .outerHTML grabs the element AND what's inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this function into Jquery core:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
return (s)
? this.before(s).remove()
: jQuery("&lt;p&gt;").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}


$('#myTag').outerHTML();
```

Source [here](http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/).

Answer (score 0):

outerHTML is not supported in firefox. You could try something like this :

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");

alert(outerHTML(image));

function outerHTML(elem){
    if (typeof elem.outerHTML !== "undefined")
    {
        return elem.outerHTML;
    }

    var s = "<" + elem.nodeName.toLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++)
    {
        s += " " + elem.attributes[i].name + '"' + escape(elem.attributes[i].value) + '"';
    }

    if (elem.hasChildNodes())
    {
        return s + ">" + elem.innerHTML + "</" + elem.nodeName + ">";
    }

    return s + " />";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To set the html for an element, you just use the .html() function, but pass it the string you want to set the html as: `$('#image').html('<span>Hello</span>')`

Comment: I think s/he want's to *get* the html of the element/object, not set it.

Comment: The question is about getting the HTML, not setting it. :)

Comment: The example with the span was unrelated.  Just an example to explain how the two things were different.