# Return HTML tag as string using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string

I created a DOM fragment using JQuery:

```
var $content = $("<div /", {id:"content"})
```

I want to output the fragment as a string, so I attempted:

```
$content.html();
```

That returns an empty string, because there are no children. How can I return a string containing:

```
<div id="content" />
```

Comment: Isn't your <div> missing its closing tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have anything in its API to do this directly, but you can use the native `.outerHTML` property.

```
$content[0].outerHTML
```

...but Firefox doesn't support this, so you can do something like this...

```
$content[0].outerHTML || $('<div>').append($content.clone()).html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m22fn/

*Note that a `<div>` tag doesn't self-close.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm only using it for debugging, so I can work around the firefox issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652771/1183294) is a link to a previously answered question that I think fits what you're looking for.

Also it would would probably be best if your first line of code is written like:

`var $content = $("<div></div>", {id:"content"});`

This way it's valid html.