# How to transform element to string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I don't need innerHTML i need innerHTML **with** enclosing tags. Lets write some example:

```
<div id="1" style="qwe"><span class="1"></span></div>
<div id="2" style="asd"><span class="2"></span></div>
<div id="3" style="zxc"><span class="3"></span></div>
```

I can get element by id:

```
$("#1")
```

And how can i get string like that:

```
<div id="1" style="qwe"><span class="1"></span></div>
```

Of course html() doesn't work becouse it will return only span.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Object to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: Actually, to select the element with `id=1` you would need to use `$('#\\31 ')`, not `$('#1')`. See http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#01.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
alert( $('#\\31 ').wrap("<div />").parent().html() )
$('#\\31 ').unwrap()
```

Comment: Actually, to select the element with `id=1` you would need to use `$('#\\31 ')`, not `$('#1')`. See http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#01. (I know it’s just an example, but hey, it doesn’t work.)

Comment: @MathiasBynens thx for this, i was still used to ID's being not valid as numbers froum HTML4 ;)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work fine:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return s
        ? this.before(s).remove()
        : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};

var outer = $("#1").outerHTML();
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFuL3/1/).

**Additional Info**

See http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/ for original article .

Comment: `string outer` and not `var outer`? Learning something new every day..!

Comment: @ChrisKempen, no, `var outer` is correct. Sometimes my brain thinks C# when writing JS.

Comment: Haha no probs! Liking your solution, +1!

Comment: It happens with everyone ;) I've just seen a foreach in javascript :)

Comment: Umm....https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach...:)

Comment: It would be better to use the native `.outerHTML` property where available, and only create the new `<p>` if it’s really necessary. [My answer mentions a plugin that does this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9176995/96656)

Answer (score 2):

Use this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-outerhtml/blob/master/jquery.outerhtml.js

```
/*! Copyright (c) 2006 Brandon Aaron (brandon.aaron@gmail.com || http://brandonaaron.net)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) 
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 */

(function($){
  var div;

  $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    var elem = this[0],
      tmp;

    return !elem ? null
      : typeof ( tmp = elem.outerHTML ) === 'string' ? tmp
      : ( div = div || $('<div/>') ).html( this.eq(0).clone() ).html();
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Use it as follows:

```
$('#some-element').outerHTML();
```

Comment: this is a pretty clean solution that only takes more effort for lame browsers... +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outerhtml` but in `JavaScript` over the `DOM` and not `jQuery`, for example:

```
  var text = document.getElementById('hello').outerHTML;
```

jsbin code to demonstrate:
http://jsbin.com/obutul/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: This doesn't work in firefox (possibly some other browsers too)

Comment: Although just checked, and it looks like a release with outerHTML implemented is fairly imminent https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92264

Answer (score 0):

There is also an [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML) property on html elements, which includes the selected element itself.

Comment: ..but have a close look on the browser compatibility table.

Answer (score 0):

outerHTML is implemented across nearly all browsers now (including old versions of ie - firefox is the only one dragging its feet, but it's [scheduled for v11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML)), so I've adapted @James Hill's answer to use this native functionality where present as it should be more efficient.

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return this[0].outerHTML ? this[0].outerHTML :
           s ? this.before(s).remove()
             : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};

var outer = $("#1").outerHTML();
```

Be aware though that there are a few cross-browser inconsistencies in outerHTML (e.g look at [this page](http://kangax.github.com/jstests/outerHTML_test/) in chrome and compare with ie)

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the desired div in another div and then fetch the parent div's html.

```
<div><div id="1" style="qwe"><span class="1"></span></div></div>
<div><div id="2" style="asd"><span class="2"></span></div></div>
<div><div id="3" style="zxc"><span class="3"></span></div></div>
```

Now,

`$("#1").parent().html()` will fetch the desired string.

Comment: Sorry - a bit slow to comment. This is slightly unworkable because it either a) involves changing the html in advance, so can't be used on any arbitrary element; or b) means you have to inject a div into the DOM using JS, which might mess with other code which expects a different DOM tree.

Comment: I mentioned you 'can'. If you cant , dont use it . Keep it simple :)

Comment: Also, who told you to change the markup, we have clone().

See the second answer,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html