# How to get the selector string from inside the on method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jQuery plugin that calls the `on` method. Now I need to get the selector string from inside that method. Is there a way I can do that?

```
(function($) {

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $(document).on('click', 'a[href="#post"]', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                // I need to get the 'a[href="#post"]' string from here
        });
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

See my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871974/how-get-svg-code-from-html-page-using-jquery-javascript-or-jqery-svg/9872076#9872076) if you need to display your "a" tag as string

```
$('<div>').append($this.clone()).html();
```

jsFiddle available here

> http://jsfiddle.net/F3Vrk/

Answer (score 1):

really not sure what you are after but you have full access to the element within the `on()` method using `this`

```
(function($) {

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $(document).on('click', 'a[href="#post"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            alert( $(this).attr('href') );
       });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

As for the actual selector string... it is hard coded into your example so not really sure what you are asking with regard to that part

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not supply this information, but there are other approaches that come to mind. For example:

```
(function() {
    var selector = 'a[href="#post"]';
    $(document).on('click', selector, function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(selector);
    });
})();
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/KXXXK/)**.

However this is a somewhat questionable practice and it's likely that there are other, simpler, ways to achieve your aim.