# How to convert the html object to string type?

Tags: string, html-parsing

I use jQuery method to get some type of html object:

```
var content = $('#cke_ckeditor iframe').contents().find('.cke_show_borders').clone();
```

Then I want to convert it to `string` type:

```
console.log(content[0].toString());
```

but the result is:

```
[object HTMLBodyElement]
```

How can I turn it into real string?

By the way, can I turn the converted html string to the html object?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I believe you want to use [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

`console.log(content.outerHTML)`

Comment: This worked to prove to me that it was working.
console.log(JSON.stringify(content[0].outerHTML))

Comment: This worked - I was stuck trying to use `.toString()` and `JSON.stringify` with no luck

Comment: typeof content.outerHTML still showing object

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

`var docString = "<html>"+content.documentElement.innerHTML+"</html>"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `content[0].prop('outerHTML')`

It worked for me

Reference : [How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/how-do-you-convert-a-jquery-object-into-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
content.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to Convert a jQuery object into a string:

var content = $('#cke_ckeditor').find('.cke_show_borders').eq(0).clone();

console.log(content.get(0).outerHTML);

Answer (score 0):

'outerHTML' working for me.

In Google Tag Manager 'custom javasctipt' part {{Click Element}} returns [object HTMLElement].

```
function() {
   var elm = {{Click Element}};
   return elm.outerHTML; // working
}
```

Result -

```
<i _ngcontent-c1="" class="material-icons">edit</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `content.innerHTML` This will solve your issue