# Unable to convert object to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, input, type-conversion

I have an input box in my HTML

```
<input id="myInput">
```

I've tried

```
var myString = (document.getElementById("myInput").toString());
```

and

```
var myString = String(document.getElementById("myInput"));
```

but doing `console.log(myString);` will always return `[object HTMLInputElement]`

How do I get `console.log(myString)` to actually return the string the user entered

Comment: What are you expecting to get instead?

Comment: If you want the user input, use `.value`

Comment: If you want `'<input id="myInput">'` use `.outerHTML`

Comment: adding `.value` got what I wanted and worked, thanks.

Comment: Edit the question to clarify what you're trying to do, so people can answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

By using document.getElementById("myInput") you get the whole input object. This object contains many properties, which you can access.
If you want the user input, you can access it by using
`document.getElementById("myInput").value`

Comment: How do you know that's what they want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the object should have a "data" property you can access for the values using dot notation. Also this link has some solutions 
[How to convert the html object to string type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344832/how-to-convert-the-html-object-to-string-type)