# Parse a string in jquery, change something and get the modified string back

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I have a string containing html code, something like this: http://jsbin.com/ocoteg/1.
I want to parse this string, make some changes (just for example: change all links to a span), and then get the modified html string back.

Here is a jsbin, where I started this, but I can't make it work: http://jsbin.com/okireb/1/edit.

I get the html string, I parse it with jquery, but I can't replace the links, and get the modified html string back.

**UPDATE**

Why the downvote? What is the problem with this question?

Comment: When you create the jQuery object `dom`, jQuery removes the elements `html` and `body` (there can't be more than one per document). I don't think any jQuery solution that creates an object from the HTML of an entire document will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a loop also

```
dom.each(function(i,v){
  if(v.tagName == "A"){
    dom[i] = $('<span/>').html($(v).html())[0]; // replace it right away with new span element
  }
});

var newString = $('<div>').append(dom.clone()).html(); //<-- to get new string http://stackoverflow.com/a/652771/1385672
console.log(newString);​
```

EDIT:

Here's how you can do it keeping the other tags

```
var dom = $(text.split('\n'));  

$(dom).each(function(i,v){ 
  var ele = $(v)[0];      
  if($(ele).is('a')){            
     dom[i] = $('<div>').append($('<span/>').html($(v).html())).html();        
  }
});

var newString = dom.get().join('\n');
```

http://jsbin.com/okireb/32/edit

Comment: This can be also a solution, but how I get back my modified html string?

Comment: dom is an array, but I need the html string.

Comment: @TamasPap I forgot to change them back into Dom elements.. heres an example http://jsbin.com/okireb/16/edit

Comment: I think we are very close to the solution, but I want to get the modified html string in a javascript variable, that looks exactly like the html on http://jsbin.com/ocoteg/1, except the links that were replaced with spans.

Comment: The problem is, that some lines dissapear: `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `html`, `head`, `body`. In my case I really have to get also this lines back, especially the doctype part. I'm still looking to solve this, but if I will not find other solution I will accept yours. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TamasPap do you care about the whitespace?

Comment: No. I care about the dissapeared doctype.

Comment: I tested it out, but in the newString the links aren't changed with spans.

Comment: @TamasPap fixed it.. this was a fun one :)

Answer (score 1):

Use find instead of filter :

```
var dom = $('<div>'+text+'</div>');
dom.find('a').each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var html = el.html();
  var span = $('<span/>').html(html);
  el.replaceWith(span);
});    
console.log(dom.children()); ​
```

Note that I wrap everything for the case where the initial dom isn't one element.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5sBxP/)

To get the html back as a string use

```
var html = dom.html();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because `find` will find nothing in this case.
If it works for you, please link a working demo, because for me it's not.

Comment: I see, and with your html it is working, but with the html I linked it's not.

Comment: In the new version (see edit) I added the wrapping I had mentioned before.

Comment: It seems the changes were maded, but how I get the full modified html string back?

Comment: Can you link a demo? I tried it here, but doesn't seem to work correctly: http://jsbin.com/okireb/24/edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20710/discussion-between-tamas-pap-and-dystroy)

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want (can be improved)

```
var text = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8 /><title>JS Bin</title></head><body><a href="#">Link 1</a><a href="#">Link 2</a><a href="#">Link 3</a></body></html>';
var body_content = text.substring(text.indexOf('<body>') + 6, text.indexOf('</body>'));
var $dom = $('<div/>').html(body_content);
$('a', $dom).each(function() {
    $('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>').insertAfter($(this));
    $(this).remove();
});
var text_new = text.replace(body_content, $dom.html());
// text_new contains the entire HTML document with the links changed into spans
```

Comment: +1 For the simplicity. This can be also a solution. I accepted wirey's because he answered first, but I really appreciate your solution.
Thank you Toni!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with .replace.
Probably not the nicest way of doing it though.

```
dom = dom.replace(/<a /g,'<span');
dom = dom.replace(/<\/a>/g,'</span>');
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/okireb/14/edit

Comment: I think it _is_ the nicest method, one-liners FTW!!

Comment: Using regex for html parsing is always dangereous. Here it would fail with a `<area` for example. People always try to make it more complex but it always fail in the end... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Very true. I've added a space. I don't think it's the best way of doing it at all but it works for this. I love the bottom of this comment though - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1791606

Comment: It works in this case, but will not solve my more complex, real world problem. Thanks for sharing this tip!