# jQuery get image's HTML as string

Tags: jquery, html, image

How do I get the html of an image with jQuery?

I want this as the output:

```
<img src="pokerface.png" alt="pokerface" />
```

I'm trying with this, but I'm getting an empty string (or null):

```
var imageHtml = $("#user-dialog .product-item img").html();
```

The following returns the **Object**, but I want the html

```
var imageHtml = $("#user-dialog .product-item img")
```

How do I do that?

**If I try with**

```
var imageHtml = $("#user-dialog .product-item img").attr("src");
```

I get the correct source of the image (`pokerface.png`), so I know it's the correct element.

Comment: `$('#selector').html()` should return the HTML according to the jQuery docs. ( http://api.jquery.com/html/ ) Did you check if your selector is correct?

Comment: Could you just recreate the HTNL? Grab the object and build a new HTML string from that.

Comment: @Thew "In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any element." It gets the element HTML contents, not the element's own HTML; e.g. it gets the elements `innerHTML`.

Comment: @DACrosby Woops, read his question wrong. Sorry!

Comment: @DACrosby - Ahhh thanks, that solved my issue. img was unneccessary in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image is the only element inside the container you could do this:

```
$("#user-dialog .product-item img").parent().html();
```

Otherwise you can create a dummy element and append the img object to it to get the .html() value.

```
$('<div>').append($("#user-dialog .product-item img").clone()).html();
```

The solution is proposed here
[How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)

Comment: I solved it now, thanks to you guys! Instead of $("#user-dialog .product-item img").parent().html(); I simply did this: $("#user-dialog .product-item").html();

Answer (score 17):

```
jQuery("#user-dialog .product-item img").get(0).outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 5):

You're effectively looking for the `outerHTML` (in those browsers that support it):

```
var imageHtml = $("#user-dialog .product-item img").map(function(){
        return this.outerHTML;
    }).get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EPq6q/).

This will, of course, return an array of the `img` element's HTML; which allows jQuery to collate *all* the relevant information, rather than explicitly iterating through the matched set with `get()` or using bracket-notation indices `[n]`

And a simple (seriously, it's *very* simple) plugin to retrieve the `outerHTML` of the matched elements:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.htmlOuter = function () {
        var self = this,
            len = self.length,
            _tmp = document.createElement('div'),
            _h = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            _tmp.appendChild(self[i].cloneNode());
            _h.push(_tmp.innerHTML);
            _tmp.innerHTML = '';
        }

        return _h;
    };
})(jQuery);

var images = $('img').htmlOuter();
console.log(images);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EPq6q/1/).

Note that the above returns an array, whereas, ordinarily, jQuery getters return results from only the *first* element of a matched set, if that's what you'd prefer then you could alter the final line of the plugin to:

```
return _h[0];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EPq6q/2/).

Oh, and obviously (like `.text()` and other getter methods) this explitly cannot be chained, given that it returns an array, or a string (if you preferred), *not* the jQuery object.

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).
  - [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML).
  - [`outerHTML` compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t05).