# How to get an image HTML which parent has more children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the whole HTML tag of an image (`<img src="url" ... />`). I can do it with `.html()` function if I refer to its parent:

```
<div id="image">
  <img src="url" />
</div>
```

and with JQuery:

```
$('#image').html()
```

But how could I do it if I don't have an image "only" parent:

```
<div id="image">
  <img src="url" />
  <!-- Here some stuff. E.g. -->
  <div><p>Something</p></div>
</div>
```

If I do `$('#image').html()` here, I'll get the whole content. If I do `$('#image img').html()` I'll get an empty string.

How could I get the whole `<img>` tag here?

Comment: Why do you need its HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get image's HTML as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516665/jquery-get-images-html-as-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML)

```
$('#image img').prop('outerHTML')
$('#image img')[0].outerHTML //in this case you need to test whether $('#image img')[0] exists
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vPR6C/)

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: Be aware that this won't work below Firefox 11.

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript, it's as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('image').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].outerHTML
```

and as **cookie monster** says,

**A nice alternative if IE6/7 support isn't needed would be** `document.querySelector("#image > img").outerHMTL`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/peYU7/)**

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this has the same problem as `.html()` mentioned in the question - OP wants the _outer_ html...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to this when you are using jQuery

Comment: @connorspiracist I'm just giving alternatives, in case there's somebody who looks here who *isn't* using **JQuery.**

Comment: A nice alternative if IE6/7 support isn't needed would be `document.querySelector("#image > img").outerHMTL`

Comment: @cookiemonster Do I have to list *everything?*  Edited :)

Comment: Yes... yes you do. ;-)