# How to bind jQuery elements using KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

This is the HTML I'm trying to bind to.  I would like to know how to bind the result of menuInnerHtml to the navigationMenu div.  Right now the output is: [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object] instead of the actual html.

`<div id="navigationMenu" data-bind="html: get_Menu()"></div>`

```
var menuInnerHtml = $();
var GlobalNavMenuViewModel = {

        get_Menu : function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if(i % 2 == 0 )
                {
                    menuInnerHtml += $("<li></li>").attr('class', 'L1').html("someInfo");
                }
            }
            return menuInnerHtml;
        }
    }

    // Bind Html
    ko.applyBindings(GlobalNavMenuViewModel);
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: It's outputing [object] and not the html

Comment: return menuInnerHtml.html() - I think that way.

Comment: BTW, very strange approach. I would suggest to create observable property and bind to it from all places you need and not reverse: bind one place of html to another html...

Comment: For something like <li> in your sample - use templates in html, with bind'ed values from viewModel. I think this is "knockout way"

Comment: I did .html() and it yielded nothing.

Comment: As far as the "knockout way" my actual if structure for binding kinda complex so I'd like to just bind html I generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using  **jqueryobject.prop('outerHTML')** (in sample **jqueryobject** is **obj**) to get the string form of JQuery Object. 
>   you can more information about jquery object to string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)

When we use **HTML** binding, the function should return string of html element


For **HTML**

```
<div id="navigationMenu" data-bind="html: get_Menu()"></div>
```

For **Javascript**

```
var menuInnerHtml = "";
var GlobalNavMenuViewModel = {

    get_Menu: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                var obj = $('<li />',{'class':'blue'}).html('peekaboo');
                menuInnerHtml+=obj.prop('outerHTML');

            }
        }
        return menuInnerHtml;
    }
}

// Bind Html
ko.applyBindings(GlobalNavMenuViewModel);
```

Working sample is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/13801/)