# Get entire opening tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Let's say the HTML is:

```
<div id="page" class="someclass"> more divs </div>
```

How do I get the entire opening tag and its attributes (but not the closing tag) as it shows in the HTML by using the ID? For example:

```
$('#page').tag();
```

Would then return:

```
<div id="page" class="someclass">
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: He wants to get the whole tag, like he said.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string

Comment: @JaredEitnier he wants to get the _starting_ tag

Comment: @RuneFS to be fair to Jared, that clarification came after the original question was posted. :)

Comment: @DA Yes yes I only posted to make it clear when reading the question (one might after all not necessarily see a comment to another answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could always use the DOM element attribute outerHTML

```
$(selector)[0].outerHTML
```

which simply gets the first DOM element of the selection and then acquires the html using the DOM attribute outerHTML

**EDIT** If you do not want the content but only the enclosing tag you could do this

```
$.fn.tag = function(){
    return this[0].outerHTML.replace(this.html(),"");
};
```

or if you only want the start tag

```
$.fn.startTag = function(){
    return this[0].outerHTML.split(this.html())[0];
};
```

you can then use it like this to get the enclosing tag

```
$("#page").tag();
```

or like this to get the start tag

```
$("#page").startTag();
```

Comment: Hello thank you but this returns the HTML of the entire DIV and is the same as $('#page').html(). I would like it to only return "<div id="page" class="someclass">".

Comment: @P.Henderson you dont what the closing tag either?

Comment: @DA yeah but now it returns the tag as well (and taking the comment into account not the content

Comment: Yes, that's right. The only output I want is '<div id="page" class="someclass">'.

Comment: +1 for introduce me to **outerHTML** which seems supported by all major browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @P.Henderson I've included an option for the enclosing tag and one that returns just the start tag

Comment: You have now mixed up startTag() and tag() (i.e: startTag returns the whole thing), but other than it works real well so thank you.

Comment: Warning, the second part of the answer will fail if the contents of the element are short strings, like `<a href="contacts.html">contacts</a>` will return `<a href=".html"></a>` or `<a href="`

Answer (score 5):

You can define a jQuery method that returns the `outerHTML` property.

```
$.fn.tag = function() {
   return this.first().clone().empty().prop('outerHTML');
}

$('#page').tag();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2FAb/

For removing the closing tag:

```
$.fn.tag = function() {
   var r = this[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
   return this.first()
              .clone()
              .empty()
              .prop('outerHTML')
              .replace('</'+r+'>', '');
}
```

For more than one selected element, the following returns an array:

```
$.fn.tag = function() {
   return this.map(function() {
      var r = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
      return $(this).clone()
                    .empty()
                    .prop('outerHTML')
                    .replace('</'+r+'>', '');
   }).get();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using plain old JavaScript simple string manipulation. Find the first closing angle bracket, then take everything up to that point.

```
function getElementStartTag(element) {
    var html = element.outerHTML;
    var index = html.indexOf(">");
    var startTag = html.substring(0, index + 1);
    return startTag;
}
```

**Example**

```js
function getElementStartTag(element) {
  var html = element.outerHTML;
  var index = html.indexOf(">");
  var startTag = html.substring(0, index + 1);
  return startTag;
}

var element = document.getElementById("testSubject");
var startTag = getElementStartTag(element);

alert(startTag); 

// output: <p id="testSubject">
```

```html
<p id="testSubject">
  <strong>Ignore</strong> this content.
</p>
```

For JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/owj7w1hu/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4FLPs/3/)

First, you get the containing element and then you get the html text of this element.
Then, you split the text by `>` and you got the text you wanted.

This will work only if there are no elements inside the containing element before your `page` div. To solve this, you can wrap the `page` div with a simple element(div?) and it will work.

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    var elem = $("#page").parent().html();
    var arr = elem.split('>');
    $("#result").text(arr[0] + " >");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="page" class="someclass"> more divs </div>
</div>
<br />

Result: <br />
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: [How do you convert a jQuery object into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)

You need to take your element, clone it, put it into a DIV, and then grab the HTML of said div.

```
alert( $('<div>').append($('#page').clone()).remove().html() )
```

If you don't want any child elements or content, then wipe out the contents first after you clone it:

```
alert( $('<div>').append($('#page').clone().html('')).remove().html() )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but this too will return the entire DIV (<div id="page" class="someclass"> more divs </div>), instead of just the <div> tag and its attributes.

Comment: @P.Henderson so you don't want the child elements...just this item?

Comment: Yes, now you're very close. Is there anyway to delete the closing tag as well?

Comment: @P.Henderson at that point, you'll have to deal with it as a string. Possibly using regular expressions.

Comment: I would suggest that perhaps you could explain what your end-goal objective is here. There might be a better way to accomplish what you are after if we had a better understanding of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this based on @Rune answer:

```
var outer = $("#page")[0].outerHTML;
var inner = $("#page")[0].innerHTML;
var result = outer.replace(inner,"");
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

 $.fn.startTag = function () {
      // this would act as backup
      var currInnerHtml = this.html();
      // you will need to have some unique string as inner html in order to split using that as in some cases innerHtml might be empty or might have some common ones that would hinder with proper splitting
      var uniqueString = performance.now();
      this.html(uniqueString);
      const startTag = this[0].outerHTML.split(uniqueString )[0];
      this.html(currInnerHtml);
      return startTag;
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are saying you don't want it wrapped with jQuery, you can always just use:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('page');
```

Alternatively you can keep using jQuery and use:

```
var ele = $("page").get(0);
```

`$("page")` returns an array, `.get(0)` returns the 1st element of that array

Comment: Hello thank you but your solution returns DOM I want the HTML of the entire tag.