# Browsers don't load these dynamically inserted images

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, dom, cross-domain

I'm using the Wolfram|Alpha API by using a proxy to fetch the XML file over AJAX, which is working excellently. I then use `find()` to look for some `pod` elements in that XML file. Those `pod`s contain images which I want to embed in my page. So far, so good. I got the images out of the file and figured out how to append them to the container. That's where I hit a snag: the images do not appear. They are there when I inspect, but they do not load.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$.get(queryURL, function (data) {
    var wapods = $(data).find("pod");
    if (wapods.length !== 0) {
        $("#container").html('<div id="wabox"><a href="http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=' + query + '" title="Wolfram|Alpha results for: ' + readQuery + '"><img id="walogo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/Wolfram_Alpha_logo.svg/200px-Wolfram_Alpha_logo.svg.png" width="150" height="18" alt="Wolfram|Alpha"/></a></div>');
        $("#wabox").append($(wapods[0]).find("img")[0])
        .append($(wapods[1]).find("img")[0]);
    }
});
```

The image that is included when the element is created appears as expected. The other two images do not. When inspected in Firefox, the inspector says "Could not load the image". This occurs in Chrome as well. This is not due to addons; it occurs in a fresh profile as well.

My best guess is something to do with the transition from having the element in an XML file to inserting it into the HTML DOM, but I don't know.

**Edit: if I right click and select "Edit as HTML" in the inspector, change one thing, and then exit the editor, the image appears. Still no clue why.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are ont he right track. An element can't just be moved from an XML document to an HTML document.

Try to get the html code for the elements (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string)), and append that:

```
function getHTML(el) {
  return $('<div>').append(el.clone()).html();
}

$("#wabox").append(getHTML($(wapods[0]).find("img").first()))
  .append(getHTML($(wapods[1]).find("img").first()));
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is exactly what I needed. Why did you use `.first()` instead of `[0]`? Also, exactly why *can't* you just move an element?

Comment: @Ian: I used `first()` so that the element is still wrapped in a jQuery object, so that you can use `clone()` on it. When an element is created it has a document as owner, see [ownerDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.ownerDocument), and it can't change owner.

Comment: OK, thanks. I had read about owners before but didn't fully understand it until now.