# Select element options not appending on dynamically added row

Tags: javascript, jquery

why does appending values of select values in `foo function` dos not trigger when I click add row button?

```
  $(document).on("click", '.tdAdd', function () {
      //alert($(this).closest('tr').index());
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";
      cols += '<td><input type="button" value="Add Row" class="tdAdd"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="tdAdd"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" /></td>';
      cols += '<td><select class = "t">' + foo($(this).closest('tr').index() + 1) + '</select></td>';
      newRow.append(cols);
      newRow.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
  });
```

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8r0rdcLf/2/) for demo.

```
  function foo() {
      var select = $('.t')
          .append($("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", 'one')
          .text('One'));
      select = $('.t')
          .append($("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", 'two')
          .text('Two'));

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems, first of which is `foo()` doesn't return anything so you are trying to concatenate `undefined` into your string.

Next what you are doing inside `foo()` doesn't make sense since `$('.t')` is a collection of every element in the page with that class.

---

The following will clone the first select, set it's value to null and then return the html to be added into your string

```
  function foo(index) {
      var $select = $('.t:first').clone().val('');
      return $select.html(); // return the innerHtml of the select as string
  }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8r0rdcLf/3/)**</kbd>

---

To really simplify your whole addRow, you could clone a whole row , reset the values of the form controls and append that clone... all without needing any new strings

```
$(document).on("click", '.tdAdd', function () {
    var $currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $newRow = $currentRow.clone();
    $newRow.find(':input').val('');
    $currentRow.after($newRow);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are trying to add the options to the next row of current 'tr' which would always been the next row available in DOM (the one which was originally next to the current row - Orange row). To add options in row you are preparing in code you have to first add it to DOM and then insert the options tag.

Minimal changes to your code :

```
 $(document).on("click", '.tdAdd', function () {
      //alert($(this).closest('tr').index());
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";
      cols += '<td><input type="button" value="Add Row" class="tdAdd"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="tdAdd"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" /></td>';
      cols += '<td><select class = "t"></select></td>';
      newRow.append(cols);
      newRow.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
      foo($(this).closest('tr').index() + 1);//add options once the newly created 'select' is available in DOM
  });
```

Comment: my bad I forgot about the foo() but that foo() is still messy

Comment: I already mentiond in my answer that these are minimal changes. Though i know this can be handled in multiple ways :)

Answer (score 1):

You were appending the JQuery object. I have extracted the HTML and appended that. ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-a-string)):

```
function foo(index) {
    var select = $("<option></option>")
                 .attr("value", 'one')
                 .text('One')
                 .prop('outerHTML');
    return select;
}
```

I have updated the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8r0rdcLf/7/